# How To use FilterExpression in Google Analytics Data API in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to use the new Google Analytics Data API to pull in some very simple data from our GA4 property and into a spreadsheet.

This all works great.

However I now want to apply some Dimension Filters so that It returns only those rows that match the filter.

This is the code I've added but I think the format is wrong.

```
const dimensionfilter = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpression();
dimensionfilter.filter.fieldName = 'pageTitle';
dimensionfilter.filter.stringFilter.value = 'MYPAGETITLETEXT';
```

There are no examples in Apps script for adding DimensionFilter etc

Has anyone done this? Has anyone got any very simple examples.

Many thanks in advance.

Here is my full code

```
   function runReport() {
  const propertyId = '29045017783';

  try {
    const metric = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
    metric.name = 'screenPageViews';


    const pagetitle = AnalyticsData.newDimension();
    pagetitle.name = 'pageTitle';

    const pagepath = AnalyticsData.newDimension();
    pagepath.name = 'pagePath';

    const dateRange = AnalyticsData.newDateRange();
    dateRange.startDate = '2022-05-01';
    dateRange.endDate = 'today';


    const dimensionfilter = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpression();
    dimensionfilter.filter.fieldName = 'pageTitle';
    dimensionfilter.filter.stringFilter.value = 'MYPAGETITLETEXT';


   

    const request = AnalyticsData.newRunReportRequest();
    request.dimensions = [pagetitle, pagepath];
    request.metrics = [metric];
    request.dateRanges = dateRange;
    request.limit=10;
    request.dimensionFilter = dimensionfilter;

    const report = AnalyticsData.Properties.runReport(request,'properties/' + propertyId);

    if (!report.rows) {
      Logger.log('No rows returned.');
      return;
    }

    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    const dimensionHeaders = report.dimensionHeaders.map(
        (dimensionHeader) => {
          return dimensionHeader.name;
        });
    const metricHeaders = report.metricHeaders.map(
        (metricHeader) => {
          return metricHeader.name;
        });
    const headers = [...dimensionHeaders, ...metricHeaders];

    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    const rows = report.rows.map((row) => {
      const dimensionValues = row.dimensionValues.map(
          (dimensionValue) => {
            return dimensionValue.value;
          });
      const metricValues = row.metricValues.map(
          (metricValues) => {
            return metricValues.value;
          });
      return [...dimensionValues, ...metricValues];
    });

    sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length)
        .setValues(rows);

    Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO (Developer) - Handle exception
    Logger.log('Failed with error: %s', e.error);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not using the google analytics reporting API you are using the Google analytics data api.  There is a diffrence.

Comment: Sorry @DaImTo I've been doing so much reading I got myself mixed up. Although the question still remains.

I can't find any App script examples of doing this. It's driving me made.

Hopefully google improve the Help Documentation/Examples. This move to GA4 is going to be a nightmare for companies who have a lot of non-GA4 scripts/code :(

Comment: UA and GA4 are completely different your going to have a very hard time converting things.    Is this not working? [Analytics Data Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analyticsdata)   The api is still in beta so google is looking for feedback there is a link at the bottom of [Help](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/help) contact us.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo yes, I'm  aware :) That's why I'm starting now to work on scripts that will achieve similar results/output to what we have now.

Most of it is working pretty well apart from these damn Dimension filters. So hopefully someone has some examples/help/advice for me in how to setup the obbject/vars etc.

What I am doing in the meantime is to run a second script after this one to tidy /clean the data. Not as efficiency but it works.

Comment: I can ping the team and check if they are working on any more samples.   I will get back to you.

Comment: @DaImTo That would be brilliant if you could. I'm a TC with Google but on the Blogger side of things and don't have any contacts with the GA/API Teams.

Would be great to get and updated Apps Script example that showcased how to do Dimension Filters with one or more filters eg FILTER1 AND FILTRER2  , or FILTER1 or FILTER2 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can apply Dimension Filter

```
const dimensionfilter = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpression()
dimensionfilter.filter = AnalyticsData.newFilter()
dimensionfilter.filter.fieldName = 'pageTitle'
dimensionfilter.filter.stringFilter = AnalyticsData.newStringFilter()
dimensionfilter.filter.stringFilter.value = 'MYPAGETITLETEXT'
```

#### Edit: For multiple filters

To combine multiple filters with `OR` condition

```
const pageTitles = [
  'MYPAGETITLETEXT1',
  'MYPAGETITLETEXT2'
]

const dimensionfilter = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpression()
dimensionfilter.orGroup = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpressionList()
dimensionfilter.orGroup.expressions = []

for (const pageTitle of pageTitles) {
  const filterExpression = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpression()
  filterExpression.filter = AnalyticsData.newFilter()
  filterExpression.filter.fieldName = 'pageTitle'
  filterExpression.filter.stringFilter = AnalyticsData.newStringFilter()
  filterExpression.filter.stringFilter.value = pageTitle
  dimensionfilter.orGroup.expressions.push(filterExpression)
}
```

You can refer to this document to understand [How method signatures are determined](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#how_method_signatures_are_determined)

Comment: Thank you so so much dikesh. This is perfect and just what I needed.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. How would I adapt the above code to have multiple filters eg

Filter1 AND Filter2  
or
Filter1 OR Filter2

I'm not sure how to construct the code.

Comment: For now we are using `filter` parameter of `FilterExpression` but for multiple filters you will have to use `andGroup` of `FilterExpression`. Have a look at reference doc for [FilterExpression](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression)

Comment: @DarkUFO Added the code for multiple filters.

Comment: Wow, that is so kind of you.  Can I buy you a beer or coffee.

Comment: Haha.. Thanks to @DaImTo for posting the question in Google group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244470/discussion-between-darkufo-and-dikesh).

Comment: One last comment.

Looking through the documentation, like in the example Dikesh has posted, we can have multiple pagetitles to check for and the OR or AND can be performed on these to limit the results being returned.

Reading further into the documentation it appears, unless I've misread the documents, that it's not yet possible to perform a "NOR" on this.

ie provide a list of PageTitles that you want excluded from the results.

Comment: @DarkUFO  Have a look at `notExpression` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to work out how to add filters so thanks for this. I wanted to add a exclusion filter, to filter out some country spam! I thought with GA4 we were past spam in Analytics.. Anyway - here is how I filtered Germany out of my request:

```js
const dimensionfilter = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpression()
dimensionfilter.notExpression = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpressionList()
const filterExpression = AnalyticsData.newFilterExpression()
filterExpression.filter = AnalyticsData.newFilter()
filterExpression.filter.fieldName = 'country'
filterExpression.filter.stringFilter = AnalyticsData.newStringFilter()
filterExpression.filter.stringFilter.value = 'Germany';
dimensionfilter.notExpression = filterExpression;
```